# what is difference b/w django-admin startapp vs python manage.py startapp?

Tags: django, django-admin-actions

1. both does the same job creating the app in projects
2. what the different between these two in **Django**?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the behaviour. django-admin comes from your installed packages while manage.py will be called from your application.